# How to Automatic Update Enterprise App without user interaction

Tags: iphone, ios, enterprise

Im currently developing an In-House Enterprise application.
I will publish the app using Apple Enterprise License.

Im currently looking for a way to perform update without having any user interaction.

As i found out that if open the update URL (eg. itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=%@/app.plist), i will be prompted whether do i want to perform the update or not.

Any other ways to perform enterprise deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to Apple Configurator (from Mac App Store) that is free. There are also other enterprise softwares, depends on your need and budget, try searching for MDM (mobile device management)...

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try Apple Configurator for the start. We do not have any budget to implement MDM. Is there any way that we can access to the data level to update the app?